# Retrieve records using epoch date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as data_stats. Please check below respective schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_stats` (
  `uuid` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `created_at` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Timestamp of when the record was created',
  `updated_at` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last updated timestamp');
```

I am storing created_at and update_at timestamp in the **epoch format**.

Now I need to find all the records that are updated today (i.e update_at date == today's date)

I tried below query

```
SELECT * FROM `data_stats` where FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at,"%Y-%m-%d") = CURRENT_DATE
```

But I am getting empty results. So how can fetch records that are updated today?

Comment: "*I am storing created_at and update_at timestamp in the epoch format.*" There is no reason to do this. `timestamp` and `datetime` are easier and faster to work with and use less storage. I would suggest converting the columns.

Comment: Can you provide some datas  ? It is working for me : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/120

Comment: [Your query works](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ibhP4AaGrMEF3K1Ln4Tvn/0), though to be safe I suggest `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at))` in case the format of `CURRENT_DATE` is different. Are you sure the rows are present? Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a mismatch in the types on the equals.  To make sure, check to see if coercing both sides to `DATE` helps.  Replace `FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at,"%Y-%m-%d") = CURRENT_DATE` with:

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at)) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
```